# Vector space $V=(\mathbb{F}_2)^2$ has exactly four vectors $(0,0),(0,1),(1,0), (1,1)$. What is implied about the field used for scalar multiplication?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am self-studying MIT OCW's 18.700 Linear Algebra course which follows Axler's book *Linear Algebra Done Right*. This course does not have solutions for the problems not contained in the book.

In the first problem set of the course, there is the following problem

> The vector space $V=(\mathbb{F}_2)^2$ has exactly four vectors
> $(0,0),(0,1),(1,0)$, and $(1,1)$; so $V$ has exactly 16 subsets.
> How many of these 16 subsets are linearly independent (l.i.)? How many bases
> does V have?

**Main conceptual questions**

First of all, I am not familiar with the notation $\mathbb{F}_2$. What is $\mathbb{F}$? $\mathbb{F}_2$ seems to be the set $\{ 0,1 \}$, and we are making length-2 lists with elements from this set. I suspect it may actually be a field (with $1+1=0$).

Second, since $V$ is a vector space it has addition and multiplication operations defined on its elements.

It seems the definition of these operations for this vector space is implicit in the problem statement. It is not clear to me what the sums $(0,1)+(1,1)$ or $(1,0)+(1,1)$ should be defined as.

If we could state that $V$ is a vector space defined over the field $\mathbb{F}_2$ defined as I did above, would this answer all these questions?

The scalar multiplication I know is tied to the field. But is the definition of addition also tied to the field? It seems that the addition operation on the vector space has a definition (which is the usual summing of the components), but then each component is composed of elements of the field, and in this field if we have $1+1=0$ then this will dictate the result. Is this true or false?

Ie, can we choose to define either of $(0,1)+(1,1)=(1,0)$ or $(0,1)+(1,1)=(1,1)$, or must we choose the first option given that addition on the field has $1+1=0$?

When we define addition and multiplication for a vector space, are these based on the field the vector space is over (is this even how to say it?), or is that field used just for the scalars in the multiplication operation?

**Here is the solution I came up with for the actual problem,** based on my interpretation above

The number of subsets is computed as $\sum_{i=0}^4 C_{V,i}$ where $C_{V,i}$ is the number of i-combinations of elements of $V$. Thus, the number of subsets is $1+4+6+4+1=16$.

Of these, each nonzero vector is l.i. on its own (3 of them), any pair not containing the zero vector is l.i. (3 of them), and the sole set with three nonzero vectors is l.i.

Thus there are 7 l.i. subsets.

As for a basis, $((0,1),(1,0))$ is a basis and hence $\dim V=2$.

There are only $C_{V-\{(0,0)\},2}$ other possibilities for a basis, but none of them work. Thus there is a single basis for $V$.

Comment: $\Bbb F$ is not a standalone symbol. Given a natural number $q$, $\Bbb F_q$ indicates the field of cardinality $q$ (it turns out that there is exactly one if $q>1$ is the power of a prime and none otherwise). For a prime $p$, $\Bbb F_p$ is described easily as the quotient ring $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$ or, equivalently, as the set $\{0,\cdots,p-1\}$ with sum and multiplication modulo $p$. $\Bbb F_{p^n}$ for $n>1$ is not quite as mundane and it's easiest defined as a quotient of the polynomial ring $\Bbb F_p[X]$ by appropriate polynomials.

Comment: Seems like I can't fully understand the concepts in your comment until I study rings in a separate course, Algebra. Is there a simpler explanation?

Comment: The only part of Sassatelli's comment that you need is that $\Bbb F_p$ is the integers mod $p$ when $p$ is prime. So yes, $\Bbb F_2$ is a field with two elements, $0$ and $1$, which satisfy $1+1=0$. And whenever $\Bbb F$ is any field, the vector space operations on $\Bbb F^n$ are: componentwise addition, and componentwise scalar multiplication.

Comment: You should also check $\{(1,0),(1,1),(0,1)\}$ is *not* LI (the incorrect claim that it is LI even contradicts your correct conclusion that $\dim V=2$), and that there is more than one basis. Indeed, any LI subset with as many vectors as the dimension of the space is automatically a basis (assuming finite dimension).

Comment: But if the only scalars we are allowed to use are 0 and 1, how do we obtain, for example, (1,0) using the set (0,1), (1,1)? This is only possible if 1+1=0. But then my question is: when we define addition on the vector space, does this addition come from the field or can we define 1+1=1 even though the field has 1+1=0?

Comment: The addition comes from the field, yes.

Comment: For any field $k$, the vector space $k^n$ is made up of $n$-tuples of elements of $k$, with coordinate-wise addition and the obvious scalar multiplication.

Comment: Is it possible to define $V=(\mathbb{F}_2)^2$ (which means its elements are length-2 lists of elements of $\mathbb{F}_2$) but then define the field used for the scalars in scalar multiplication to be, say, $\mathbb{F}_3$ (I am assuming this means it contains the elements $(0,1,2)$)?

Comment: No, there's really no way to define scalar multiplication of elements of $\Bbb F_2^2$ using $\Bbb F_3$ as your field of scalars.

Comment: You've made a couple of mistakes in counting the number of linearly independent sets and the number of bases.  The set $\{(0,1),$$\,(1,0),$$\,(1,1)\}$ of non-zero vectors is *not* linearly independent, because $(0,1)+(1,0)+(1,1)=(0,0,0)$.  Your other linearly independent sets are correct, and that's all there are, so there are only $6$ of them, not $7$. *Any* linearly independent set of $2$ vectors will be a basis for  $\ \Bbb{F}_2^2\ $. Apart from $\{(0,1),$$\,(1,0)\}$, therefore, you also have $\{(1,0),$$\,(1,1)\}$ and $\{(0,1)\,(1,1)\}$. So there are *three* bases, not just one.

Comment: In fact there are 7 linearly independent sets, but the OP missed one.  (Also another way to realize the set of three nonzero vectors can't be linearly independent is that it's larger than the basis you found!)

Comment: I have no idea why I wrote that the three element set is a basis. It obviously is not.

Comment: @JBL Yes, I mistakenly omitted the empty set from the list of linearly independent sets. There are indeed $7$ of them.

Answer (score 1):

After reading the comments on the original question and going back to Axler's book, my understanding is the following.

For a field $F$, the notation $F^n$ is the set of lists of length $n$ of elements of $F$.

For the field $\mathbb{F}_2=\{ 0, 1\}$ which has the operations $+$ and $\cdot$ defined as

$$0+0=0$$
$$0+1=1+0=1$$
$$1+1=0$$

we have that $(\mathbb{F_2})^2$ is the set

$$\{ (0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1) \}$$

where $0$ and $1$ are in $\mathbb{F}_2$.

Now, let's go in tiny steps.

When we say $V=(\mathbb{F}_2)^2$ is a vector space, we are really saying is that we have a set $V$ along with addition and scalar multiplication operations defined on the set.

Now, $V=(\mathbb{F}_2)^2$ means the elements of $V$ are length-2 lists of elements from the field $\mathbb{F}_2$. Thus, when we define addition on $V$ as the usual componentwise sums, the individual sums will be between elements of $\mathbb{F}_2$.

It seems to be the case that the scalars used in scalar multiplication on the vector space are also from $\mathbb{F}_2$.

Thus we can only multiply the elements of $V$ by $0$ and $1$.

Comment: Yes, that's right.  For any field $F$, the notation $F^n$ (without further elaboration) is understood to mean the vector space you mention with field of scalars $F$.  When you have two fields $F, K$ with $K \subset F$ (like for example $\mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{R} \subset \mathbb{C}$) then $F^n$ is also a vector space over $K$ (as is true for any $F$-vector space) but if you want to do something like that you have to explicitly specify that you're viewing $F^n$ as a vector space over $K$.